# I have a 1998 Jeep Wrangler, 2.5L. What kind of brakes are in my vehicle?

Tags: brakes, jeep

I believe I have disc brakes in the front. Is it drum brakes in the back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the fact that there are no rear brake rotors available for a 1998 Jeep Wrangler 2.5, I'd have to say that you must have drum brakes in the rear.

Comment: The rotors for a read brake are different from the ones for the front, then?

Comment: In the front you have rotors (as well as pads and calipers), while in the rear you have drums (as well as shoes and wheel cylinder). All parts mentioned are different between front and rear, and are not interchangeable.